# jQuery drag-and-drop demo works. Now how to make it a form that can be submitted?

Tags: jquery

[This](http://plugins.scbfolio.com/jquery_drag_drop_select/#Events) is exactly the behaviour I want: dragging items from a list to another.

Now, I would like to add a "submit" button so that I can save the chosen items on the server side.

How to do this?

- Create a hidden form, and update the input values in an `after_drop_action` method I would write in the page.
- AJAX-call the server at each `after_drop_action` (I would rather avoid it unless absolutely necessary)
- Something else? What is the usual way to do? It is basic but I have no experience with jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All suggestions so far use AJAX, but wouldn't it be better to simply have **hidden inputs**, and update their values when the drag-and-drop is used?

They would get submitted together with the form, eliminating many headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Not an AJAX on each drop, but you can use an AJAX onclick of the submit button to send all changes to serve.

Comment: I would rather avoid any AJAX, to avoid authentication/multiplicity headaches on the server side... sorry for being a newbie, but if I don't override `after_drop_action`, does the information get stored anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

For example, if one of your three drag&drop container had an id of "container1" and you had a button with id "submit"

Html:

> ```
> <input type="button" id="submit" value="Let's go" />
> ```

Javascript:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
     var container1 = $("#container1").children().map(function(index, element) {
       return $(element).text();
     });

//Now you can send that to the server, or display a list of selected items on the screen..

        alert("Container1 has the elements " + container1.join(', ') + " in it");
    // getJSON is one of the many ways of sending stuff back to your server using jquery facilities described at http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/
        $.getJSON("your/url", {"selectedItems": container1.join(', ')}, function(response) {});
});
```

With the URL you provided, map container1 to the leftmost container and you would get something like

Container1 has the elements Item1, Item 2, Item 3, ... Item 6 in it.

Comment: I think I am missing something: Where is the input with id "submit" used?

Comment: haha, good catch :P I've edited my answer to make something with it :P

Comment: Also, I think `container1` is a duplicate variable, and it needs a `.get()` before the `.join`. With those corrections the alert works :-)